# What is "Wrong question" short for? "A wrong question" or "The wrong question" or not short at all?

Tags: articles

What is "Wrong question" short for? "A wrong question" or "The wrong question" or not short at all?

The next is "The right question".

[image]

[image]

"House of Cards" S01E01 00:47:06

Comment: @Andrew As an English learner, I NEVER accuse native speakers of their English. I know "Wrong question" is colloquial and short, but I DIDN'T know what it is short for. "A wrong question" or "THE wrong question", as I showed in my question. Thanks for your help, I now understand. Issues on articles are very difficult and puzzling, because there's no counterpart in Chinese.

Comment: This is a good question, and I see where your confusion comes from. I assume you know the general rules for the definite article in English. Normally when there is a singular right question in context, hence "**the** right question is..." And the rest is wrong questions, so you would say "That's a wrong question." When speaking informally, and with a forceful tone, people often say, "That's the wrong question." "Wong answer."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in any language, English speakers will omit unnecessary words when speaking informally or forcefully.  In this case,

> Wrong question

is short for

> That is the wrong question.

This shortened answer is somewhat *impolite* -- the reporter is deliberately *talking back* to her editor (and boss) to assert that she understands the story better than he does.  However, the next sentence follows the pattern of the unspoken sentence, *"The right question is ..."*

These kind of shortened interjections are pretty frequent.  Some examples:

> Wrong answer  (= That is the wrong answer)
>
> Good point (= That is a good point)
>
> Well done (= That was well done)
>
> True.  (= That is true)

And, now recently associated with Donald Trump:

> Wrong!  (= that is wrong)

(edit) The difference between "a" vs. "the" is a frequent question here, and one that's difficult to answer as it varies with context.  In general, "the" indicates some specific example of the thing, while "a" is non-specific, and possibly one of many similar examples.

In this case, "the wrong question" means I am thinking of a specific question -- the *right* question -- and this isn't it.  Meanwhile "a good point" means I have no particular point in mind, so the point you made is one of many possible "good points".

Comment: Why "Wrong answer = THE wrong answer", while "Good point = A good point"? As I said, I understand speakers need lots of omissions, but what I (and many others) may mistake is what they are short for, mainly when involving articles(a/an/the/zero article).

Comment: @ZhangJian  There are many questions on ELL that ask about a/the distinctions, so please search for more detail.  In this case it's simply idiomatic -- I use *the* to indicate I'm thinking of a *specific* answer (the *right* answer) rather than some answer in general.  Meanwhile, *a* good point indicates I had no specific point in mind, so yours is as good as any.  If I did have a specific point in mind, I might respond instead, *"That's the same point I was going to make"*